# gettin EXC_BAD_ACCESS while using nsstring

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I am getting crazy during 4 hours and I really need help. Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //check if strGroup has prefix and suffix #
    BOOL result;

    result = [strGroup hasPrefix: @"#"];

    if (result)
    {
        result = [strGroup hasSuffix: @"#"];

        if (result)
        {

            NSMutableString* string = [NSMutableString stringWithString: strGroup];
            str = [strGroup substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (1, [string length]-2)];

            strToHoldAllContact = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"strToHoldAllContact=%@",strToHoldAllContact);
}
```

I am gettin the value of `strToHoldAllContact` correctly. But when I try to access `strToHoldAllContact` from another method I am getting the error:

```
[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x856f2a0
```

Comment: retain it . or it will be autoreleased;  like "strToHoldAllContact = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str] retain];"   don't forget to release it when dealloc

Comment: sorry , i don't use ARC ,   or he can use property the solve the problem,

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
strToHoldAllContact = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
[[strToHoldAllContact retain] autorelease];
```

and forget about release.

Answer (score 0):

where ever you are initializing or setting the string do this `[strToHoldAllContact retain];` and don't forget to release it once you are done using it

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
strToHoldAllContact = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
```

to

```
strToHoldAllContact = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",str];
```

And release it after you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

with ARC, in .h declare strToHoldAllContact as:

```
@property(strong) NSString *strToHoldAllContact;
```

in .m, use it (after @synthesize) as `self.strToHoldAllContact = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];`
this way you will not have problems.

without ARC,in .h declare strToHoldAllContact as:

```
@property(retain) NSString *strToHoldAllContact;
```

and use it same ways as with ARC in.m file.